# Ideal WP multisite server setup for up to 1000 sites?

Tags: multisite, vps

I plan to host up to 1000 sites for a large non-profit. Each site could get quite a bit of traffic. What is the ideal setup?

VPS, *ngix, mem-cache etc?

Comment: and others - This question intrigued me so much, I asked a related question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16880/mega-wordpress-applications-wpmu-or-otherwise - I'd appreciate your insights.

Answer (score 2):

Get a dedicated box with Nginx. That'll go pretty far even before caching. It mostly depends on your traffic tho. Number of blogs matters a lot less, becasue I've seen a network with 10 blogs suck up a gig of RAM becasue of the hits it was getting.

Answer (score 1):

Chris_O's ["My WordPress Performance and Caching Stack"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2490/what-is-the-best-caching-option-for-wordpress-multi-site-on-non-shared-hosting) is the server setup I'm planning to use for my multi-site install of similar size.  Given that I can accomodate the following caveat, (from the Nginx proxy cache plugin page), I'll be very interested in seeing how many accounts (sites) a single VPS can comfortably support.

> Plugins that rely on php code running on each page view won't work properly. This is 
>   similar to wp-supercache or any of the other static caching plugins. Stats, image 
>   rotation, etc. You should implement these features via javascript or third-party 
>   services, depending.

Next steps, once the single VPS is outgrown is to move the database to a separate host, and the CDN to an external one, and have Nginx load balance between multiple apache servers.  If that's not enough, then you'll have to shard the database and probably want to move to hardware load balancing.  [The WPMUDev folks have a good overview of that type of setup.](http://wpmu.org/scaling-wordpress-wpmu-buddypress-like-edublogs/)

Comment: you need to remove "," in the end of 2nd link.