# If I use Apache & ngnix together will I have fewer problems?

Tags: apache, nginx, vps

I have a VPS set-up and because it had limited RAM I set it up to run nginx instead of apache.  But although performance has been reasonable, I've had problems with things like multi-site rules and plugins complaining.

I was wondering if I used Apache and Nginx together, with nginx serving static files, apache php would I get both performance and compatibility?  I am thinking of setting up my VPS in a similiar manner to the 2nd answer to this question:

[What is the best caching option for WordPress multi-site on non-shared hosting?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2490/what-is-the-best-caching-option-for-wordpress-multi-site-on-non-shared-hosting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use Apache & ngnix together will I have fewer problems?

Yes, of course.

Please be sure to install and setup [mod_rpaf](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/) in Apache, if you are going to setup Nginx as reverse proxy to Apache.

> I was wondering if I used Apache and Nginx together, with nginx
>   serving static files, apache php would I get both performance and
>   compatibility?

Performance is purely based how you configure these. Your site will, of course, be more compatible (for plugins).